# How do I replace the last occurrence of a character in a string using sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed

How do I replace only the last occurrence of "-" in a string with a space using `sed`?

For example:

```
echo $MASTER_DISK_RELEASE
swp-RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.0.0-03
```

but I want to get the following output ( replacing the last hyphen [“-“] with a space )

```
swp-RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.0.0 03
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can do it with single `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)-/\1 /'
```

or, using extended regular expression:

```
sed -r 's/(.*)-/\1 /'
```

The point is that `sed` is very greedy, so matches as many characters before `-` as possible, including others `-`.

```
$ echo 'swp-RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.0.0-03' | sed 's/\(.*\)-/\1 /'
swp-RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.0.0 03
```

Comment: Note, this is not portable.  Some non-GNU versions of `sed` do not support pattern matches.  In that case, you'll need something else, be it `perl -pne 's/(.*)-/$1 /'` or @Thor's parameter expansion solution or something else.

Comment: of course :-) thx...

Comment: You shouldn't need to escape those brackets when using single quotes.

Comment: @jgmjgm You can omit backslashes by using extended regular expression with `sed -r`.

Comment: Is there better way if i want it for the last 2 occurences
ex: swp-RedHat-Linux-OS 5.5.0.0 03

I'm currently doing $ echo 'swp-RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.0.0-03' | sed 's/\(.*\)-/\1 /' | sed 's/\(.*\)-/\1 /'

Comment: @VinayPotluri Try `sed -r 's/(.*)-(.*)-/\1 \2 /')`.

Comment: @jimmij that worked 
thx

Answer (score 42):

You could also handle this with [bash parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
s=swp-RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.0.0-03
echo ${s%-*} ${s##*-}
```

Output:

```
swp-RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.0.0 03
```

Comment: Very creative, love this answer

Comment: Hi Thor. Nice trick. I'd like to do this, but on a Bash array. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19):

Something like this worked for me, although I'm sure there are better ways

```
echo "swp-RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.0.0-03" | rev | sed 's/-/ /' | rev
swp-RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.0.0 03
```

Comment: This is bad...plain bad. Why do 4 operations when you can do 2?

Comment: For someone with only a basic understanding of regular expressions, this answers seems much more approachable. And who cares how many operations it takes, this is going to be instantaneous for all practical cases. So I would consider readability over some arbitrary rule to use as few operations as possible.

Comment: @Psirus I hope this isn't going to open up a can of worms, but the idea of using lesser operations is to showcase a certain level of *mastery* of the *lesser* operations. For example, @Thor's answer shows an appreciation of `bash` parameter expansion feature, which works well if OP is using `bash` too. There is going to be a delicate balance between readability (to the point of being very verbose) and using the right tools, but more often than not using the right tools prevails.