# How to align multiple lines with echo or print

Tags: text-processing

I have a script which check the mounted file system against the entry listed under fstab, the issue what I am facing here is to keep the output align.

Below is the script output:

```
/  is mounted OK
/boot  is mounted OK
/was8  is mounted OK
/was8/slogs  is mounted OK
/was8/cluster  is mounted OK
/was8/working  is mounted OK
/was8/app  is mounted OK
/was8/tools  is mounted OK
/was8/plugin  is mounted OK
/was8/coreproduct  is mounted OK
...
```

I want to keep these line aligned so it should look like this:

```
/  is mounted                       OK
/boot  is mounted                   OK
/was8  is mounted                   OK
/was8/slogs  is mounted             OK
/was8/cluster  is mounted           OK
/was8/working  is mounted           OK
/was8/app  is mounted               OK
/was8/tools  is mounted             OK
/was8/plugin  is mounted            OK
/was8/coreproduct  is mounted       OK
...
```

I have tried column  and xargs unable to get the desire result. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: hi friend, Perl suggestion works for me, Except the / file system rest all gets aligned perfectly,  There is extra tab for / file system Ok status and other file systems

Answer (score 15):

In general, when you're doing the printing, you can set the width in the format string to `printf`. `%-20s` would print a string on a field 20 characters<sup>(*)</sup> wide, unless it overflows. `%-20.20s` would make it 20 characters and drop any overflowing part.

(* Though e.g. Bash's `printf` actually counts *bytes*. The difference can be seen with characters like `ä` in UTF-8.)

So, e.g.

```
printf "%-40s %s\n" "$mountpoint  is mounted" "$status"
```

would make the first part (at least) 40 characters wide:

```
/was8/coreproduct  is mounted            OK
...
```

Or, if you need to post-process an input like that, you could use Perl or awk:

```
perl -pe 's/(.*) +(\S+)$/ sprintf "%-40s %s", $1, $2 /e'  < file

awk '{s=$NF; sub(/ *[^ ]+ *$/, "", $0); printf "%-40s %s\n", $0, s}'  < file
```

Both basically separate the last non-whitespace string, and then print the two parts with the first on a fixed-width field.

---

Or, if you don't care about keeping the separation between the fields exactly as they were, a simpler solution commented by @[JJoao](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/96276/jjoao) would be:

```
awk '{s=$NF; NF-- ; printf "%-40s %s\n", $0, s}' < file
```

That produces the below output. Note that the two-space blank before `is mounted` is collapsed to one. This happens since `awk` rebuilds the whole `$0` when `NF` or any of the fields are modified.

```
/was8/coreproduct is mounted             OK
```

Comment: cool +1; or .. `awk '{s=$NF; NF-- ; printf "%-40s %s\n", $0, s}'`

Comment: @JJoao, yeah, that's the easy way, but it collapses the two-space separation before `is mounted` :) Probably a good idea to include that in any case.

Comment: Note that `printf "%.20s"` only prints a 20 _character_ wide string with `zsh` or `fish` `printf`. With other implementations, it's 20 _byte_ wide as POSIX (unreasonably) requires. With ksh93's `printf` builtin, see also `printf "%20Ls"` for the width to be the display width (accounting for zero-width or double-width characters). For awk, YMMV depending on the implementation, with `perl`, use `-Mopen=locale` to work with characters in the locale's charset.

Answer (score 6):

Just a bit of obfuscating Perl:

```
perl -ne 'printf "%-40s %s", /(.*) (.*)/s'
```

Comment: That's not even too bad, as far as obfuscated Perl goes.

Comment: ... any way, we are getting sneaky ☺

Answer (score 4):

One way is to introduce a tab before the status code, e.g.:

```
<input rev | sed 's/ /\t/' | rev | column -s $'\t' -t
```

Output:

```
/  is mounted                        OK
/boot  is mounted                    OK
/was8  is mounted                    OK
/was8/slogs  is mounted              OK
/was8/cluster  is mounted            OK
/was8/working  is mounted            OK
/was8/app  is mounted                OK
/was8/tools  is mounted              OK
/was8/plugin  is mounted             OK
/was8/coreproduct  is mounted        OK
/was8/ihs  is mounted                OK
/was8/backup  is mounted             OK
/was8/ihs/logs  is mounted           OK
/was8/wsdm  is mounted               OK
/was8/ws  is mounted                 OK
/was8/ihs/logs/analysis  is mounted  OK
```

Comment: I think you could also something like `sed -Ee 's/(.*) +/\1\t/'` to replace the last spaces with the tab. (Stolen from here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/187889/170373 )

Comment: @ikkachu, that's the same as `sed 's/\(.*\) /\1\t/'` as the `" +"` will only ever match one space as the preceding `.*` will have eaten all the other ones.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, good point. And of course the input here didn't even have multiple spaces before the `OK`. The main point was in trying to avoid the `rev`s.

Comment: Linux_FS_CHECK () {
mount | egrep "ext|vxfs|lofs|xfs" | awk '{print $3}' > /tmp/Postcheck
        while read line
        do
        cat /tmp/Postcheck | grep $line > /dev/null
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo -e  "$line  filesystem is mounted $green(OK)";$reset
                else
                echo -e "!!!Warning!!!$line filesystem is not mounted $red(Failed)";$reset
                fi
        done < /tmp/Precheck
}
mount | egrep "ext|vxfs|lofs|xfs" | awk '{print $3}' >/tmp/Precheck
Linux_FS_CHECK
this is script which I pulled from my pre & post che

Comment: @KamalAsdeo: I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done very easily with the column utility. The key is to include some kind of differentiating marker between your 'columns'. For example, if space is the differentiating marker then `column -s ' ' -o ' ' -t` will perfectly align on spaces.

I use this frequently and have even made some nice vim macros that utilize it to align code. The general syntax you want is:

`column -s <Separator String> -o <Separator String in Output> -t`

This is a generalization of the tab based answer, but doesn't require the insertion of tabs necessarily.

Comment: Which version of `column` is this?

Comment: I'm guessing GNU. I'm on mobile atm and its trickier to check, but it works on most linuxes I use.