# Bash: substitute last occurrence of given pattern in search and replace

Tags: bash, wildcards

The [Bash Hackers
Wiki](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace) says

```
${PARAMETER/PATTERN/STRING}

${PARAMETER//PATTERN/STRING}

This one can substitute (replace) a substring matched by a
pattern, on expansion time. The matched substring will be entirely
removed and the given string will be inserted.

The first one (one slash) is to only substitute the first
occurrence of the given pattern, the second one (two slashes) is
to substitute all occurrences of the pattern.
```

This approach also works for Bash arrays, using the `array[@]` syntax.
But suppose one wants to substitute the last occurrence of the given
pattern. Bash apparently doesn't provide a way to do this.

For a single string and a pattern which is just a normal string, one
can do (see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187920/4671)

```
s=/foo/bar/baz
echo ${s%/*}/prefix-${s##*/}
```

which gives

```
/foo/bar/prefix-baz
```

But this doesn't work for arrays. However, one can write an explicit
loop over the array, like so

```
a=(foo/bar/baz foo/bar/boo)
b=()
for i in "${a[@]}"; do
    b+=("${i%/*}/prefix-${i##*/}")
done
echo "${b[@]}"
```

which gives

```
foo/bar/prefix-baz foo/bar/prefix-boo
```

So, I have two related questions.

1. Why doesn't Bash provide an option to replace the last match? Is
   this simply a unimplemented feature, or is there a technical reason
   why it is impossible to implement? Because this seems like an odd gap
   to leave. Comparisons with other shells are welcome.
2. Is there a way of replacing the last match without looping over an
   array? Apparently Zsh is what the cognoscenti use, so feel free to
   give a Zsh solution if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure they exist, but I don't know of any operator in any language that have the feature. If you look at `sed`'s `s/../../`, you can replace the n<sup>th</sup> occurrence with `s/../../n`, but not number occurrences back from the last.

I suppose that would make it too obscure a feature.

Here, you could use `ksh`'s `${var/pattern/replacement}` and back-references.

With `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob
b=("${a[@]/%(#m)[^\/]#/prefix-$MATCH}")
```

(where `(#m)` activates the capture of the matched portion in `$MATCH`)

Or:

```
b=("${(S)a[@]/%(#b)\/(*)//prefix-$match[1]}")
```

(where `(#b)` activates back-references, the capture of portions matched by `(...)` groups into elements of the `$match` array, and `S` makes the match less greedy).

With `ksh93`:

```
b=("${a[@]/%*([^\/])/prefix-\1}")
```

In `zsh`, you can also do:

```
dirs=($a:h)
new_bases=(prefix-$^a:t)
b=()
printf -v b %s/%s ${dirs:^new_bases}
```

Comment: If there is no technical reason why the last occurrence cannot be supported, would it be reasonable to submit a Bash feature request?

Comment: @FaheemMitha, the concept of "last" could also be confusing. So for instance the last occurrence of `/*` assuming you count occurrences by matching them left to right as `${..//..}` does in `foo/bar/baz` would be `/bar/baz`, not `/baz`.

Comment: Reverse, apply what you want to apply, reverse.